# Visual Basic - Blocking a window

Tags: vb.net

how do I make it so for example I have a main window of my program, and when I click on a button, it shows a popup (launches Form2) while disabling the main window (if you click on it, the popup flashes and doesn't let you tab to the main window). On default it lets you freely move between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Disable Parent Window on Show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838105/vb-net-disable-parent-window-on-show)

Answer (score 2):

Call the ShowDialog method of Form2. This will launch what's called a *modal* dialog, which has the behavior you've described.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for documentation.